# Finding Words in Cells in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to cycle through a data frame in Pandas in an effort to create an appended calculated column indicating whether or not certain words are in the Remarks column of the data frame. I am using the "in" function and it is not picking up the word in the cells. Help?

--SEE CODE BELOW--

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel("C:/Users/NJBRYAN/Desktop/02 Project Files/01 Project Data Files/Compression_Curtailment_Last_6_Mos.xlsx")

df['Suction_Related']="suction" in ['Remark']
    
df.head(4)
```

--OUTPUT--

The code compiles but does not identify the cells correctly.

[image: output]

Comment: `df['Suction_Related']=df['Remark'].str.contains('suction')`?

Comment: You the man, Henry! Nailed it.